# WPF DataTrigger that accepts parameter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger, multibinding

I have the following style defined in my XAML to enable buttons only when something in the DataContext has changed (IsDirty = true) :

```
   <!-- Style for Buttons to enable based on IsDirty value -->
    <Style x:Key="EnableWhenDirtyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- Enable button when something has changed -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                           AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.IsDirty}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="true" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

This works as long as there is only one DataContext within the UserControl.  I now have the situation where I have 3 different DataViews so I have 3 different IsDirty values (i.e., CustomerTableIsDirty, OrderTableIsDirty, OrderDetailTableIsDirty).  In this case I can create three new *DisableWhenDirtyButtonStyle in the UserControl like:

```
        <Style x:Key="CustomerTableEnableWhenDirtyButtonStyle" 
               TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
               BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CustomerTableIsDirty}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Is there a way to create a DataTrigger such that the binding value can be passed into the style as a parameter?

Alternatively, is there a way to add conditions to a MultiDataTrigger when inheriting a style via 'BasedOn' which would already have a MultiDataTrigger defined.  For instance:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomerTableEnableWhenDirtyButtonStyle" 
                   TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource EnableWhenDirtyButtonStyle}">

     <!-- Add the following to existing MultiDataTrigger in EnableWhenDirtyButtonStyle -->
     <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=CustomerTableIsDirty}" Value="true" />

</Style>
```

I CANNOT use MultiBinding as this style is part of a base project which gets used by multiple other projects (as a DLL).  The users of this DLL would not be able to update the style to include the necessary Binding Path.

Comment: How about creating attached behavior? Something like described [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/10/01/wpf-creating-parameterized-styles-with-attached-properties/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 3 different names, just use a single name IsDirty.

Comment: Because all of this is on one UserControl the values for CustomerTableIsDirty, OrderTableIsDirty, OrderDetailTableIsDirty are in one ViewModel.  Naming them simply 'IsDirty' is not an option.  I didn't mention it in my post but each table has its own save button and I am trying to enable just the specific button.